# Azure AD sign in for mobile application remove prompt consent

Tags: mobile, azure-active-directory, prompt

Is it possible to remove the consent prompt when user sign in to the mobile application?
[image: consent prompt]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below points can help:

For the mobile app registered in azure ad,please  make sure  the api permissions like delegated user permissions  (This will allow minimum compulsory permissions to be needed .) added are given/granted consent in portal itself by admin. If required add users to the application that dont need consent .
If you want the user to be verified first by the admin , don't grant it and grant after the login request for the first time.

[image]

For users in your tenant to allow access to the application, please
Go to your **Azure AD > Enterprise Applications > User settings** > `Admin consent requests` 
Here select `Users can request admin consent to apps they are unable to consent to` to **Yes** .

For ‘Who can review admin consent requests’, select the users and groups whom you  can allow to review the admin consent for the application and set the  days till when this consent is not required for those user. This way users in your tenant will not receive the admin consent prompt while trying  to access the application.

[image]

Select `Allow user consent for apps` in **User consent settings** pane  if you permanently need to remove consent for all applications in your tenant.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detail steps given, will try to request the settings from the users.

Comment: May i know for the mobile application, since my mobile app is developed using flutter, is it ok to register my mobile app as native client is Azure AD and use appauth library to authenticate user from mobile, instead of using msal android and ios for the authentication as per official documentation? I have no experience in this.

Comment: As per these references  [SO REF:authenticate-with-azure-ad-from-ios-app-using-appauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923130/how-to-authenticate-with-azure-ad-from-ios-app-using-appauth) & [aadb2candroid native with app auth](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-appauth), it looks like it is ok to use app auth with azure ad with some points to be noted as per references.